# Save the results of reading in date to a variable in vim script

Tags: date, variables, vim

Is there a way to save the results of reading the current date to a variable that can be used in a script? 
So.. I can successfully read in the current date with:

```
:r!date "+\%F"
```

Which returns:
    2018-03-28

Now I want to be able to save this 2018-03-28 to a variable that I can use later on in my script.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You could use `:help systemlist()`:

```
let now = systemlist('date "+%F"')[0]
```

or a combination of `:help localtime()` and `:help strftime()`:

```
let now = strftime("%F", localtime())
```